# Monitor node.js scripts running on ubuntu instance

Tags: node.js, monitoring

I have a node.js script that run once in a day on ubuntu EC2 instance. This script pulls data from some hundered thousand remote APIs and save to our local database. Is there any way we can monitor this node.js script on remote server? There have been few instances where script crashed due to some reason and we were unable to figure it out without SSHing into instance and checking the logs. I have however created a small system after first few crashes which send us an email whenever script crashes due to some uncaught exception and also when script completes execution.

However, we need to develop a better system where we can monitor the progress of script via web interface of our admin application which is deployed over some other instance and also trigger start/stop of script via this interface. What are possible options for achieving this?

Comment: Try using loggers, I am using `morgan` to write to file and then i am parsing that file showing logs on web page. It have different flags indicating log type as normal, warning, error, etc.  So you can just show the error logs. In your case `Winston` will may work better for you as its best for `remote-calls`.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to stay in Node.js, then there are several process monitoring tools:

[**PM2**](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) comes with lots of other features besides monitoring processes. You can monitor your processes via CLI or their official web interface:  https://keymetrics.io/. A quick search on npm also gives a bunch of nice unofficial gui tools: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pm2+web

[**Forever**](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) is not as feature rich as PM2 but will do the basic process operations and couple of gui are also available in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=forever%20web).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been using PM2 since past one and half year for running and monitoring node server but it does not fit the current scenario I need to monitor. I would prefer writing my own custom solution for monitoring within the script.

Comment: yes, it only monitors cpu/memory usage. To monitor other matrices you would need custom module.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here that you are trying to solve:

1. Scheduling work to be done
2. Monitoring a process for failure

At a simple level, this is easy: schedule a cron job and restart failed things so they keep trying.

However, when things don't go smoothly, it helps to have a lot more granularity over what you are scheduling, and how it is executed. This would also give you the visibility over each little piece of work.

Adding a little more complexity, you can end up with something like this:

1. Schedule the script that starts everything (via cron, if that's comfortable)
2. That script generates several jobs that need to be executed into a queue
3. A worker process (or *n* worker processes) consume that queue and execute pending jobs
4. You can monitor both the progress of the jobs, as well as the state of each worker (# of crashes, failures, jobs completed, etc.). The other tools mentioned above are good candidates for this (forever, pm2, etc.)

When jobs fail, other workers can pick up the small piece of work that was in progress and restart it. This is much more efficient than restarting the entire process, and also lets you parallelize things across *n* workers based on how you can split up the workloads.

You could easily throw the status onto a web app so you can check in periodically rather than have to dig through server logs.

You can also get more intelligent with different types of failures. Network error? Retry 5 times. Rated limited? Gradual back-off. Crash? Don't retry and notify via email. etc

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with pm2, you can get the info of the task, then cat out or grab the log files. Or you could have a logging server, see also: https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2